# Identification of this bug or insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this bug dead in my house in Mississauga, ON, Canada.

I didn't have a ruler around so a regular toothpick was used to show the size.

I'm thinking it's a pill bug but I want to make sure.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a pillbug, or "roly-poly", Subphylum, Crustacea, class Malacostraca, family Armadillidiidae.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillidiidae